# How to create folder, create file and change the files suffixs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-web-api, directory

I'm making a MVC-project and I need to send a friendrequest to my Web API. The call to the API should receive three parameters (string receiver, string sender and string message). Then the API should check if a directory/folder with todays date exists (YYYY-MM--DD). If it doesn't I must create one. In this directory/folder (new or old) I need to create a XML file with the name of the persons initials letters (ex. Eric Li and Adam Li = ELAL.xml) If this filename already exists I need to add a suffix like (old filename = ELAL1, new filename = ELAL2).

**How can I solve this? Any solutions?**

After that I need to save the data but that part can I figure out by myself.

Comment: Note that this is a Q&A site and not a code writing service. See also how to [ask]

Answer (score 2):

I think at first you need to separate your big task to many simple tasks.

What I see:

1. Create API for you requests
2. Create class like "IOManager" (or your cool name) who can check folders/directories, create it, if its need, and also he can create xml files
3. Create class like "NameResolver" who can get file name from user name
4. Connect all of them

Now you have 4 small tasks and you can try do it self or find in internet exemples for each of them.